# Eclipse Kepler not printing log messages

Tags: android

I have upgraded my eclipse installation to Kepler for android development. Even though the setup is more stable and zippier than Indigo, one particular problem has stumped my development flow.

Kepler is not printing the logcat output. I understand that it is not the problem with eclipse per se, as the log out put is managed by Android SDK tools (Logcat output is not printed on command line either).

I don't know if it is a problem with ADT plugin for Kepler or Eclipse installation itself. Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Comment: close the logcat and reopen the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

You try out this :

1. Update the ADT and plug-ins to latest versions
2. select the emulator on DDMS in devices option .(Is it selected)
3. Restart Emulator or Eclipse .